# Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined, Angular/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Good morning
I'm having this issue and just don't know how to resolve. This is existing code and currently creating an admin view of current users.  There is a table component we're using to bind the user data to. However, I'm getting this **Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined error** in the table component TS file.

table.components.ts

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() header;
  @Input() columns: any[];
  @Input() data;

  constructor() {}

  columnKeyValuePairs = [];
  displayedColumns = [];

  tableData: MatTableDataSource<any>;

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;

  expandedElement;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tableData.sort = this.sort;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.columns.forEach((col) => {
      let pair = Object.entries(col);
      this.columnKeyValuePairs.push(pair[0]);
      this.displayedColumns.push(pair[0][0]);
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(old) {
    if (old.data) {
      this.tableData = new MatTableDataSource<any>(old.data.currentValue);
    }
  }
}
```

From the above code, this is the line where I'm getting the error, `this.columns.forEach((col) => {`

Admin-ui.components.ts

```
export class AdminUiComponent implements OnInit {
  public users: any[] = [];
  resetUsers: any;
  @Input() header: string;  
  @Input() columns: [
    { userName: "User Name" },
    { firstName: "First Name" },
    { lastName: "Last Name" },
    { email: "Email" },
    { roleId: "Role ID" },
    { statusId: "Status ID" },
  ];
  @Input() data: any[];  

  constructor(    
    private userService: UserService,    
  ) { }  
 
  ngOnInit(): void {   
    this.userService;
    
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data.users;
      console.log(data.users); 
     
    });
  }
}
```

admin-ui.components.html

```
<div class="admin">
    <app-table [header]="header"
               [data]="users"
               [columns] = "columns">
    </app-table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admin UI

```
export class AdminUiComponent implements OnInit {
      public users: any[] = [];
      resetUsers: any;
      @Input() header: string;  
      columns = [ // Remove @Input and use `=` instead of `:`
        { userName: "User Name" },
        { firstName: "First Name" },
        { lastName: "Last Name" },
        { email: "Email" },
        { roleId: "Role ID" },
        { statusId: "Status ID" },    
      ];
...
}
```

table Component:

```
....
ngOnInit(): void {
  if(Array.isArray(this.columns))
    this.columns.forEach((col) => {
      let pair = Object.entries(col);
      this.columnKeyValuePairs.push(pair[0]);
      this.displayedColumns.push(pair[0][0]);
    });
  }
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Admin-ui.component.ts

```
export class AdminUiComponent implements OnInit {
  public users: any[] = [];
  resetUsers: any;
  @Input() header: string;  
  columns = [ // Remove @Input and use `=` instead of `:`
    { userName: "User Name" },
    { firstName: "First Name" },
    { lastName: "Last Name" },
    { email: "Email" },
    { roleId: "Role ID" },
    { statusId: "Status ID" },
  ];
  ...
```

Comment: thanks....unfortunately that doesn't work. This is what I had initially. I will still get the same error.

Comment: are you using <app-table>  on the other part of the AdminUI component? seems like the approved answer is same as what i did.